# Selecting multiple counts with JPA

Tags: java, sql, jpa, jpql

I have an Entity Ticket, which is based off the TICKET table.

```
|TICKETID|CUSTOMER|PRIORITY|
|1001    |CUST1   |3       |
|1002    |CUST2   |4       |
```

I want to return a table with customer and counts of priorities, e.g.

```
|CUSTOMER|P1|P2|P3|P4|
|CUST1   |0 |0 |1 |0 |
|CUST2   |0 |0 |0 |1 |
```

How do I achieve this using JPA/JPQL? I can return a result set using SQL relatively easily, so I might create a view in the database.

My first thought is to create an Entity Count, using a JPQL statement to retrieve each count. This makes it really easy to add to a JSF table.

My issue is, not having used JPQL before, I have no idea how/where to implement it!

Edit:

MY question is, how do I set up the classes to get a result set from my Ticket Entity?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT a.customer as customer, a.priority as p1, b.priority as p2,
c.priority as p3, d.priority as p4
FROM ticket as a
INNER JOIN ticket  AS b ON  a.customer = b.customer
INNER JOIN ticket  AS c ON  c.customer = b.customer
INNER JOIN ticket  AS d ON  c.customer = d.customer;

Not really efficient, though.
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I'm struggling to understand how to return the results to JSF. As far as I can tell, I need an entity to be able to use `<h:dataTable var = "_ticket" value="#{tickets}">` in the xhtml document. I'm not sure how to put this into another class.

Comment: That's a whole different question, isn't it?

Comment: @Gimby Not necessarily, I'm asking: What should my class structure look like in order to return the result set of a query. I know what the query is, I just don't know where to put it and how to implement it. I've been looking at criteria builder, but again I don't know where to put it.

Comment: Your idea of using a database view and then creating a JPA entity to match it does not sound too bad to me. Anything else is answered by the JEE tutorial and/or a good book on JPA.